# Settings bundle - PSMultiValueSpecifier - multi select

Tags: iphone, appsettings, multi-select

Is it possible to select more than one value using PSMultiValueSpecifier at settings bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.  You'll have to use a series of boolean properties.  Note that you can embed one list within another to have them not clutter up the main section.